# trying to submit a form in Go and it isnt working

Tags: go

I built an interactive resumé page that contains a form. I'm trying to send a message, using form  in `go` and it isn't working. It's just keep taking back to the home page when I click on the `submit` button.

I want to receive a message when the user click the `submit` button.

I also want the sender to receive a confirmation that the message has been delivered.

This is my main.go file

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "text/template"
    )

    func main() {
      http.HandleFunc("/", routeIndexGet)
      http.HandleFunc("/process", routeSubmitPost)
    
      fmt.Println("server started at localhost:9000")
      http.ListenAndServe(":9000",nil)
    }
    
    func `routeIndexGet`(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
      if r.Method == "GET" {
        var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("form").ParseFiles("index.html"))
        var err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    
        if err != nil {
          http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
      }
    
      http.Error(w, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
    
    func routeSubmitPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      if r.Method == "POST" {
        var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("result").ParseFiles("index.html"))
    
        if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil{
          http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
          return
        }
        var name = r.FormValue("name")
        var email = r.FormValue("email")
        var subject = r.FormValue("subject")
        var message = r.Form.Get("message")
    
        var data = map[string]string{"name": name, "email":email, "subject": subject, "message":message}
    
        if err := tmpl.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
          http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
    
      }
    
      http.Error(w, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
```

This is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <title>MeetMe - Resume Website Template</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Icon -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/simple-line-icons.css">
        <!-- Slicknav -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/slicknav.css">
        <!-- Menu CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/menu_sideslide.css">
        <!-- Slider CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/slide-style.css">
        <!-- Nivo Lightbox -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/nivo-lightbox.css" >
        <!-- Animate -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
        <!-- Main Style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
        <!-- Responsive Style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
    
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <!-- Header Area wrapper Starts -->
        <header id="header-wrap">
          <!-- Navbar Start -->
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar indigo">
            <div class="container">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                  <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                  <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
                <ul class="onepage-nev navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end clearfix">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#hero-area">
                      Home
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">
                      About
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#services">
                      Services
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#resume">
                      Resume
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolios">
                      Work
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">
                      Contact
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
            <ul class="onepage-nev mobile-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about">about</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#services">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#resume">resume</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#portfolio">Work</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Mobile Menu End -->
          </nav>
          <!-- Navbar End -->
    
          <!-- Hero Area Start -->
          <div id="hero-area" class="hero-area-bg">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                  <div class="contents">
                    <h5 class="script-font wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">Hi This is</h5>
                    <h2 class="head-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Omoyibo Oghenetega</h2>
                    <p class="script-font wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">Back-end Web Developer</p>
                    <ul class="social-icon wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                      <li>
                        <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="icon-social-twitter"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="icon-social-instagram"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="linkedin" href="#"><i class="icon-social-linkedin"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="google" href="#"><i class="icon-social-google"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="header-button wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-common">Get a Free Quote</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Hero Area End -->
    
        </header>
        <!-- Header Area wrapper End -->
    
        <!-- About Section Start -->
        <section id="about" class="section-padding">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="img-thumb wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/gallery/FB_IMG.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="profile-wrapper wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                  <h3>Hi Guys!</h3>
                  <p>I build digital product for web and mobile and i also maintain existing web and mobile project</p>
                  <div class="about-profile">
                    <ul class="admin-profile">
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> Name </span> <span class="pro-detail">Omoyibo Oghenetega</span></li>
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> Age </span> <span class="pro-detail">23 Years</span></li>
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> Experience </span> <span class="pro-detail">1 Years</span></li>
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> Country </span> <span class="pro-detail">Nigeria</span></li>
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> Location </span> <span class="pro-detail">portharcourt, Rivers state</span></li>
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> e-mail </span> <span class="pro-detail">tomoyibo@gmail.com</span></li>
                      <li><span class="pro-title"> Freelance </span> <span class="pro-detail">Available</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-common"><i class="icon-paper-clip"></i> Download Resume</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-speech"></i> Contact Me</a>
                </div>
              </div>   
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- About Section End -->
    
        <!-- Services Section Start -->
        <section id="services" class="services section-padding">
          <h2 class="section-title wow flipInX" data-wow-delay="0.4s">What I do</h2>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <!-- Services item -->
              <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="services-item wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                  <div class="icon">
                    <i class="icon-grid"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="services-content">
                    <h3><a href="#">Back-end Development</a></h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse condi.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Services Section End -->
    
        <!-- Resume Section Start -->
        <div id="resume" class="section-padding">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="education wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                  <ul class="timeline">
                    <li>
                      <i class="icon-graduation"></i>
                      <h2 class="timelin-title">Education</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="content-text">
                        <h3 class="line-title">Bsc In Electrical engineering  university</h3>
                        <span>2015 - 2020</span>
                        <p class="line-text">Expenses as material breeding insisted building to in. Continual so distrusts pronounce by unwilling listening. Thing do taste on we manor.</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="content-text">
                        <h3 class="line-title">Higher Secondary School - French village international college</h3>
                        <span>2009 - 2014</span>
                        <p class="line-text">Expenses as material breeding insisted building to in. Continual so distrusts pronounce by unwilling listening. Thing do taste on we manor.</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="content-text">
                        <h3 class="line-title">Secondary School - Labratory High School</h3>
                        <span>2005 - 2010</span>
                        <p class="line-text">Expenses as material breeding insisted building to in. Continual so distrusts pronounce by unwilling listening. Thing do taste on we manor.</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="experience wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                  <ul class="timeline">
                    <li>
                      <i class="icon-briefcase"></i>
                      <h2 class="timelin-title">Experience</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="content-text">
                        <h3 class="line-title">junior back - end Developer</h3>
                        <span>Jan 2020 - Present</span>
                        <p class="line-text">Expenses as material breeding insisted building to in. Continual so distrusts pronounce by unwilling listening. Thing do taste on we manor.</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="content-text">
                        <h3 class="line-title">software developer</h3>
                        <span>Nov 2019 - Dec 2020</span>
                        <p class="line-text">Expenses as material breeding insisted building to in. Continual so distrusts pronounce by unwilling listening. Thing do taste on we manor.</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="content-text">
                        <h3 class="line-title">software developer</h3>
                        <span>Mar 2015 - Oct 2016</span>
                        <p class="line-text">Expenses as material breeding insisted building to in. Continual so distrusts pronounce by unwilling listening. Thing do taste on we manor.</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Resume Section End -->
    
        <!-- Portfolio Section -->
        <section id="portfolios" class="section-padding">
          
        </section>
        <!-- Portfolio Section Ends --> 
    
        
        <!-- Contact Section Start -->
        <section id="contact" class="section-padding">      
          <div class="contact-form">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row contact-form-area wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">          
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="contact-block">
                    <h2>Contact Form</h2>
                    <form id="contactForm">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required data-error="Please enter your name">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required data-error="Please enter your email">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div> 
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" required data-error="Please enter your subject">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group"> 
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" rows="5" data-error="Write your message" required></textarea>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="submit-button">
                            <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                            <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div> 
                            <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>            
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="footer-right-area wow fadeIn">
                    <h2>Contact Address</h2>
                    <div class="footer-right-contact">
                      <div class="single-contact">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                        </div>
                        <p>portharcourt, rivers state</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="single-contact">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <p><a href="mailto:hello@tom.com">tomoyibo@gmail.com</a></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="single-contact">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                        <p><a href="#">+(234) 813 685 9270</a></p>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <object style="border:0; height: 450px; width: 100%;" data="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d34015.943594576835!2d-106.43242624069771!3d31.677719472407432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x86e75d90e99d597b%3A0x6cd3eb9a9fcd23f1!2sCourtyard+by+Marriott+Ciudad+Juarez!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1533791187584"></object>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>   
        </section>
        <!-- Contact Section End -->
    
        <!-- Footer Section Start -->
        <footer class="footer-area section-padding">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="footer-text text-center wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                  <ul class="social-icon">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                          <div class="img-thumb wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/gallery/zuri.png"i4g.png" alt="">
                          </div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                          <div class="img-thumb wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/gallery/hng.png" alt="">
                          </div>
                        </div>                
        <!-- Services Section End -->
                    <u1>
                    <li>
                      <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="github" href="#"><i class="icon-social-github"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="icon-social-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="icon-social-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="icon-social-google"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <p>Copyright © 2018 UIdeck All Right Reserved</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Footer Section End -->
    
        <!-- Go to Top Link -->
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top">
          <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
        </a>
    
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/wow.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="assets/js/nivo-lightbox.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/form-validator.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/contact-form-script.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/map.js"></script>
          
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no `action` attribute on your form, so by default it would submit back to the same page, not `/process` and the page wuld reload without any effect. You need to tell it where to post the data. Unless of course that `assets/js/contact-form-script.min.js` is what does the submitting (it probably is, in which case you should also have posted that).

Comment: you can read more about HTML forms at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form and https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/submit

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no `action` attribute on your `contactForm`. Due to that, when you submit, it will submit to the page itself instead of the route you wanted it to submit to.

Consider adding an `action` attribute:

```html
...
<form id="contactForm" action="/process">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                ...
```